# Cant connect info to listbox whis is in one more listbox in WP7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have a class News

```
public class News : ObservableCollection<New>
{
    public News()
        : base()
    {

    }
}
```

A class New

```
public class New : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
         public PhotoAttachments Photo
    {
        get
        { 
            return photoAttachments;
        }
        set
        {
            photoAttachments = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Photo");
        }
    }
   // some fields such as date, text, id, sourceName etc
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
{//realisation of method}
 public PhotoAttachments photoAttachments = new PhotoAttachments(); // it is a collection, such as News, but it contains objects of class PhotoAttachment, which have property with string url to photo
}
```

after 
`InitializeComponent();` i write `this.listBox.ItemsSource = NewsList;`
so a have a listbox with objects of class New. 
In these listbox I created another one listbox, and tried to fill it by PhotoAttachments collection. And here I have a problem, listbox with photos don't show photos(but they exists). Here is XAML:

```
// I can select different      <local:NewsTemplateSelector.Photos>
//style of listbox               <DataTemplate>
//using  NewsTemplateSelector     <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"  Width="400" Height="300" Margin="10">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" Height="300">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Height="75" Width="75" Margin="0,-225,0,0" />
                                            <Canvas Width="400">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="65" Width="326" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment, Height" />
                                                <ListBox Name="photoListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Photo}"  Height="229" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="326" Canvas.Top="69">
                                                    <Image  Source="{Binding Big}" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="400" />
                                                </ListBox>
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:NewsTemplateSelector.Photos>
```

PhotoAttachment class:

```
    public class PhotoAttachment : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string ownerId;
    public string OwnerId { get { return ownerId; } set { ownerId = value; OnPropertyChanged("OwnerId"); } }
    private string small;
    public string Small { get { return small; } set { small = value; OnPropertyChanged("Small"); } }
    private string big;
    public string Big { get { return big; } set { big = value; OnPropertyChanged("Big"); } }
    public PhotoAttachment(string ownId, string small, string big)
    {
        ownerId = ownId;
        this.small = small;
        this.big = big;
    }
    public PhotoAttachment() { }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for PhotoAttachment class? Have you checked if it is not an issue with binding the image itself (binding to Big property)?

Comment: updated. I tried binding to Small and Big, but no result. When I run the aplication, I can see in main listbox item a listbox, but it don't show photo, it just has a list with strings "ProjectName.PhotoAttachment"

Comment: also, if i define in New just one photoAttachment, and instead of listbox with photos, I put just an image - I can see these image using string  `<Image  Source="{Binding photoAttachment.Small}" Height="200"  Width="400" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized that your XAML for photoListView is missing an ItemTemplate

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image  Source="{Binding Big}" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="400" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks) but now, I have a list of ALL photos in each item if the main listbox) but its another question)